# Find all partial matches to vector of unsigned

Tags: c++, algorithm, pattern-matching

For an AI project of mine, I need to apply to a factored state all rules that apply to its partial components. This needs to be done very frequently so I'm looking for a way to make this as fast as possible.

I'm going to describe my problem with strings, however the true problem works in the same way with vectors of unsigned integers.

I have a bunch of entries (of length N) like this which I need to store in some way:

```
__a_b
c_e__
___de
abcd_
fffff
__a__
```

My input is a single entry `ciede` to which I must find, as fast as possible, all stored entries which match to it. For example in this case the matches would be `c_e__` and `___de`. Removal and adding of entries should be supported, however I don't care how slow it is. What I would like to be as fast as possible is:

```
for ( const auto & entry : matchedEntries(input) )
```

My problem, as I said, is one where each letter is actually an unsigned integer, and the vector is of an unspecified (but known) length. I have no requirements for how entries should be stored, or what type of metadata is going to be associated with them. The naive algorithm of matching all is O(N), is it possible to do better? The number of reasonable entries I need stored is <=100k.

I'm thinking some kind of sorting might help, or some weird looking tree structure, but I can't seem to figure out a good way to approach this problem. It also looks like something word processers already need to do, so someone might be able to help.

Comment: Some clarification questions: (1) are all entries the same length? i.e. can we assume that each of the _m_ entries is essentially an _n_-dimensional integer vector (with some dimensions unspecified)? (2) Do you have known bounds for the individual elements (e.g. every integer is between −10 and +10)?

Comment: Does _ mean a wildcard value or would ckekl also be a match?

Comment: Maybe an [Interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Higher_Dimensions) is a good direction, at least if the `_` “wildcards” can be represented as finite intervals.

Comment: @mindriot all entries are the same length, but in theory if you want you could also store them "sparsely" (as pairs of value/id), and there would be no problems. The length of the input is always the same. I do not have bounds for elements unfortunately, other than they are unsigned. Some upper bound could be forced on the users if it can bring really critical improvements, but I'd prefer not to have to do that.

Comment: @PaulR. _ means that anything can match that. I just used it to show that matches must take into consideration the positions of the elements. _ do not need to be stored explicitly if one does not need to. ckekl would only match c_e__

Comment: @PaulR. Note that a single _ matches one and one character (value) only. Entries are all the same length and aligned also because of that.

Comment: You mention vector elements are unsigned integers, presumably 32 or 64 bits. Are they uniformly distributed or do you expect some values occur a lot more frequently than others? Also how long are these vectors, 10s, 100s or 1000s of elements? How many percent of elements are "wildcards"? I know a parallel scan with GPU might be super fast but I'm trying to think of something with C++ and CPU. I also assume you'll want 100% accurate results.

Comment: @NikoNyrh This work is for a library, so precise distributions of values and length of vectors is in theory unknown (since they depend on the user), but I'd say 100 elements vectors should be a reasonable upper bound, with much shorter vectors the common case. The values themselves have upper bounds provided by the user but they can go quite high if needed, so here I'd like to be flexible. Wildcards are completely random because they depend completely on the problem at hand that is being decomposed. 100% accurate results are needed, yes.

Comment: Hi, would you have a somewhat large set of input and query data? As we know optimizing and benchmarking with small datasets isn't fun. Generating test data is a bit tricky, for example I don't know the percentage of wildcards in patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) containing your entries. When searching the trie, you start in the root and recursively follow an edge, that matches character from your input. There will be at most two of those edges in each node, one for the wildcard `_` and one for the actual letter.

In the worst case you have to follow two edges from each node, which would add up to O(2^n) complexity, where n is the length of the input, while the space complexity is linear.

A different approach would be to preprocess the entries, to allow for linear search. This is basically what compiling regular expressions does. For your example, consider following regular expression, which matches your desired input:

```
(..a.b|c.e..|...de|abcd.|fffff|..a..)
```

This expression can be implemented as a [nondeterministic finite state automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), with initial state having ε-moves to a deterministic automaton for each of the single entries. This NFSA can then be turned to a deterministic FSA, using the standard [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).

Although this construction can increase the number of states substantially, searching the input word can then be done in linear time, simply simulating the deterministic automaton.

Below is an example for entries `ab`, `a_`, `ba`, `_a` and `__`. First start with a nondeterministic automaton, which upon removing ε-moves and joining equivalent states is actually a trie for the set.

[image]

Then turn it into a deterministic machine, with states corresponding to subsets of states of the NFSA. Start in the state `0` and for each edge, other than `_`, create the next state as the union of the states in the original machine, that are reachable from any state in the current set.

For example, when DFSA is in state `16`, that means the NFSA could be either in state `1` or `6`. Upon transition on `a`, the NFSA could get to states `3` (from `1`), `7` or `8` (from `6`) - that will be your next state in the DFSA.

The standard construction would preserve the `_`-edges, but we can omit them, as long as the input does not contain `_`.

Now if you have a word `ab` on the input, you simulate this automaton (i.e. traverse its transition graph) and end up in state `238`, from which you can easily recover the original entries.

Comment: I suppose the trie is the same algorithm proposed by @Frank. The other one I'm not sure, since my goal is not to find a word given the patterns, but rather find the patterns given the word, which I suppose is the opposite of what regexes do.

Comment: that is true for regexes, but after the transformation the states of the underlying DFSA correspond to subsets of the states of the original NFSA, where the terminating states represent the entries you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in a tree, 1st layer represents 1st element (character or integer), and so on. This means the tree will have a constant depth of 5 (excluding the root) in your example. Don't care about wildcards ("_") at this point. Just store them like the other elements.

When searching for the matches, traverse the tree by doing a breadth first search and dynamically build up your result set. Whenever you encounter a wildcard, add another element to your result set for all other nodes of this layer that do not match. If no subnode matches, remove the entry from your result set.

You should also skip reduntant entries when building up the tree: In your example, `__a_b` is reduntant, because whenever it matches, `__a__` also matches.

Comment: I like this solution, however my main concern is how big the tree is going to be since there's going to be a node for every single "letter" in my entries - from when they diverge onwards, before they would be shared. Also pruning redundant entries is not an option, since `__a_b` and `__a__` actually need to be separate, since I need to sum certain values from each matching label depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an algorithm in mind which I plan to implement and benchmark, but I'll describe the approach already. It needs `n_templates * template_length * n_symbols` bits of storage (so for 100k templates of length 100 and 256 distinct symbols needs 2.56 Gb = 320 MB of RAM. This does not scale nicely to large number of symbols unless [succinct data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure) is used.

Query takes `O(n_templates * template_length * n_symbols)` time but should perform quite well thanks to bit-wise operations.

Let's say we have the given set of templates:

```
__a_b
c_e__
___de
abcd_
_ied_
bi__e
```

The set of symbols is `abcdei`, for each symbol we pre-calculate a bit mask indicating whether the template differs from the symbol at that location or not:

```
aaaaa    bbbbb    ccccc    ddddd    eeeee    iiiii
....b    ..a..    ..a.b    ..a.b    ..a.b    ..a.b
c.e..    c.e..    ..e..    c.e..    c....    c.e..
...de    ...de    ...de    ....e    ...d.    ...de
.bcd.    a.cd.    ab.d.    abc..    abcd.    abcd.
.ied.    .ied.    .ied.    .ie..    .i.d.    ..ed.
bi..e    .i..e    bi..e    bi..e    bi...    b...e
```

Same tables expressed in binary:

```
aaaaa    bbbbb    ccccc    ddddd    eeeee    iiiii
00001    00100    00101    00101    00101    00101
10100    10100    00100    10100    10000    10100
00011    00011    00011    00001    00010    00011
01110    10110    11010    11100    11110    11110
01110    01110    01110    01100    01010    00110
11001    01001    11001    11001    11000    10001
```

These are stored in columnar order, 64 templates / unsigned integer. To determine which templates match `ciede` we check the 1st column of `c` table, 2st column from `i`, 3rd from `e` and so forth:

```
         ciede  ciede
__a_b    ..a.b  00101
c_e__    .....  00000
___de    .....  00000
abcd_    abc..  11100
_ied_    .....  00000
bi__e    b....  10000
```

We find matching templates as rows of zeros, which indicates that no differences were found. We can check 64 templates at once, and the algorithm itself is very simple (python-like code):

```
for i_block in range(n_templates / 64):
    mask = 0
    for i in range(template_length):
        # Accumulate difference-indicating bits
        mask |= tables[i_block][word[i]][i]

        if mask == 0xFFFFFFFF:
            # All templates differ, we can stop early
            break

    for i in range(64):
        if mask & (1 << i) == 0:
            print('Match at template ' + (i_block * 64 + i))
```

As I said I haven't yet actually tried implementing this, so I have no clue how fast it is in practice.